# SFXs that step-up d12s from the Doom Pool

Tags: cortex-plus, marvel-heroic-roleplaying

Several SFX involve taking a die from the Doom Pool and adding it to your pool, then steping it up and returning it to the Doom Pool.

For example:

> **SFX: Berserk.** Add a die from the doom pool to one or more attack
> actions. Step up the doom pool die by +1 for each action; return it to
> the doom pool when you’re done.
>
> **SFX: Eye of Agamotto.** Add a doom die to your next action including an
> Arsenal of the Herald or Master of the Druidic Ways power. After your
> action, step up the doom die and return it to the doom pool.

What if that Doom die is a d12? Does it mean the character gets a free d12 to his actions as long as there is one in the Doom Pool?

On one hand I can understand the logic of "those characters shine when the situation is really dire".

On the other hand, a free d12 on all actions seems a bit broken, and unfair to the other characters.

How to handle those situations?

Answer (score 9):

This part from page OM06 of the core rules should help:

> You can’t step dice up beyond d12—usually the rules tell you something else happens (such as a hero being stressed out by taking more than d12 stress); otherwise **you should step up the next highest die on hand (such as in a dice pool).**

Comment: What the... I've been GMing that campaign for more than four years, and this is the first time I hear about this rule. My life is a lie. This is going to change a lot of things, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The rule on OM06 tells you to step up the next highest die available. (As @Magician stated).

There may be rare situations where there is no other such die, such as when your Doom Pool is a single die, or only has d12's in it. Or when an SFX directs you to step up a specific trait die, such as Boost or Burst.

In these situations where you may need to step up a d12, one solution is to replace the d12 with a d12 and a d6. It's a natural progression, and if multiple steps occur after that you can just continue to step up the d6.

Comment: Is replacing a d12 with a d12 and a d6 a houserule or is it based on some rule? Also, why a d12 and d6 instead of a d12 and d4?

Comment: It's a house rule based on "stepping up the Doom pool". When a player rolls a 1 you can pay them a PP and step up the lowest die in the Doom Pool, or add a d6. If you think of this whole process as "I get a d6 and I can either add it directly or use it to step up another die", then it makes a logical sense to think of the whole stepping up process as adding a d6.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to be clear that it was a houserule (and one that sounds pretty sensible). I'm still curious though, why not add a d4? That seems to me like one step, since it's the smallest die, whereas a d6 sounds like two steps, since it's the second smallest die.

Comment: You could in fact use a d4 step, since adding a d4 to any die is the same as stepping it up. The reason I start this progression at d6 is that Distinctions tell us that adding a d4 to your dice pool is a penalty (because of the high risk of rolling opportunities). Since this is intended to be a benefit, starting at a d6 avoids that. In the same way that activating Opportunities adds a d6 to the Doom Pool, not a d4, and Assets always start at d6, not d4. Again, not a perfect rationale, but there's enough precedent to make the argument.